# Как удалить строку содержащую определенное слово

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу составит адресную книжку, и не могу разобраться с функцией удаление. По задумке человек должен написать имя на английском, а программа ищет строку в которой это находится и удаляет.
Строка с "Имя" выглядит таким образом :

```
print("Для удаления контакта введите имя контакта, которого необходимо удалить: ")
nam = input("Введите имя: ")
```

Я только начинаю и еще много чего не понимаю, поэтому обращаюсь сюда
весь код :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
from colorama import init 
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import io
import pickle
init()

print( Back.GREEN )
print( Fore.BLACK )

print("Адреса из Книги:")
f = open('Adress Book.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    print (line)

print( Back.BLACK )
print( Fore.WHITE )

running = True

while running:
    print("Найти или Добавить контакт?")
    what = str(input("Введите действиe:") )
    if what == "Добавить":
        print("Для добавления нового контакта введите Информацию о нем:")
        name = input( "Имя Контакта: " )
        surname = input( "Фамилия: " )
        gos = input("Страна Проживания: ")
        adr = input( "Адрес Эл.Почты: " )
        ph = input("Номер Телефона: ")
        print("Вы добавили контакт " + name + " " + surname + " В свою адресную книжку")

        my_filename=str("Adress Book")
        fext2='txt'
        with open(my_filename + '.' + fext2, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
             print(name,surname,gos, adr,ph, file=fp, sep=" | ")
     
             fp.close()# закрытие файла

    if what == "Найти":
        print("Для поиска данных о контакте введите имя + фамилию требуемого вам контакта: ")
        nam = input("Введите имя + фамилию: ")
        nam = nam.replace(" ", " | ")
        print("Все данные на имя " + nam)
                #!/usr/bin/env python
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
        word = nam
        with io.open('Adress Book.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            for line in file:
                if word in line:
                    print(line, end='')
    if what == "Удалить":
        print("Для поиска данных о контакте введите имя + фамилию требуемого вам контакта: ")
        nam = input("Введите имя + фамилию: ")
        nam = nam.replace(" ", " | ")

        running = True
```

---

так выглядит фрагмент из файла `Adress Book.txt`:

```
Nikita | Fedotov | Russia | example@gmail.com | +79533435645 
Aleksey | Aleksandrov | Russia | aleksandrov1989@gmail.com | +7955343664
```

Comment: покажите пример вашей адресной книги

Comment: Прикрепил к посту

Comment: отлично, добавьте пожалуйста пару строк из файла `Adress Book.txt`

Comment: Nikita | Fedotov | Russia | example@gmail.com | +79533435645
Aleksey | Aleksandrov | Russia | aleksandrov1989@gmail.com | +79553436645

Comment: я не совсем понял вашу задумку в том смысле как вы храните и обрабатываете строки, но самый простой способ, это получить имя фамилию, считать все строки например в список и парсить их. если нашлось - удалить из списка. по окончанию перезаписать измененный список в файл

Comment: Моя задумка такова : Человек пишет Имя, программа находит совпадение и удаляет строчку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я добавил для вас некоторые строки, проверьте:

```
#from __future__ import print_function
#import re
from colorama import init 
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
#import io
#import pickle

init()

print("Адреса из Книги:")
print(Back.GREEN, Fore.BLACK)

#f = open('Adress Book.txt')
#for line in f.readlines():
#    print(line)

# readlines - считывает из файла все строки в список и возвращает его.
with open('Adress Book.txt') as f:                                             # +++
    my_lines = f.readlines()                                                   # +++
print(*my_lines, sep='\n')    
print(Back.BLACK, Fore.WHITE)

#running = True
print("Найти или Добавить контакт?")
while True:  # running:
#    what = str(input("Введите действиe:") )
    what = input("\nВведите действиe (Добавить, Найти, Удалить или Enter-выход): ")
    if what == "Добавить":
        print("Для добавления нового контакта введите Информацию о нем:")
        name = input( "Имя: " )
        surname = input( "Фамилия: " )
        gos = input("Страна Проживания: ")
        adr = input( "Адрес Эл.Почты: " )
        ph = input("Номер Телефона: ")
#        print("Вы добавили контакт " + name + " " + surname + " В свою адресную книжку")

        my_filename = str("Adress Book")
        fext2 = 'txt'
        with open(my_filename + '.' + fext2, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
             print(name, surname, gos, adr, ph, file=fp, sep=" | ")
#             fp.close()# закрытие файла происходит автоматичкский
        print(Back.GREEN, Fore.BLACK)
        print(f"Вы добавили контакт в адресную енигу: {name}, {surname}, {gos}, {adr}, {ph}")
        print(Back.BLACK, Fore.WHITE)

#    if what == "Найти":
    elif what == "Найти":
        print("Для поиска данных о контакте введите имя + фамилию требуемого вам контакта: ")
        nam = input("Введите: <имя> <фамилию> ")
        nam = nam.replace(" ", " | ")
        print("Все данные на имя: " + nam)
        word = nam
        with open('Adress Book.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            print(Back.GREEN, Fore.BLACK)
            for line in file:
                if word in line:
                    print(line, end='')
        print(Back.BLACK, Fore.WHITE)
                    
#    if what == "Удалить":
    elif what == "Удалить":
        print("Для поиска данных для удаления введите <имя> <фамилию>: ")
        nam = input("<имя> <фамилию>: ")
        word = nam.replace(" ", " | ")
        print("Вы хотите удвлить данные на имя: " + word)
        with open('Adress Book.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            print(Back.GREEN, Fore.BLACK)
            for line in file:
                if word in line:
                    print(line, end='')
        print(Back.BLACK, Fore.WHITE)
        nam = input("Y или y - да хочу, любой другой ввод - нет не хочу: ")   
        if nam == "Y" or nam == "y":
            print("Y или y - да хочу")
            my_lines = []
            with open('Adress Book.txt') as f:
                for line in f.readlines():
                    if not word in line:
                        my_lines.append(line) # = f.readlines()   
            with open('Adress Book.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                for line in my_lines:
                    f.write(line)

#        running = True 
    elif what == "":
        break
    else:
        print("Вы не правильно ввели действиe, повторите или нажмите Enter")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_string = "..."
banned_word = '***'
your_string = '\n'.join(i for i in your_string.split('\n') if banned_word not in your_string)
```